# Running a script having mongodb queries from mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb

I have a couple of Ids in my mongodb database document. I need to create indexes on these Ids through a script so that i do not have to run the ensureIndex command again and again.

```
db.getCollection("elements").ensureIndex({customerId:1});
db.getCollection("elements").ensureIndex({userId:1});
........
```

I just run the script (that contains all these commands) and I should be done. Any idea how to run a script from mongodb shell? Also what should be the extension of the script?

Juhi.

Comment: Do you want to run it again, or what?

Comment: You should accept helpful answers, by the way.

Answer (score 13):

You can put your commands to a javascript file (with `.js` extension) and use `mongo` console utility to run it. Like this:

```
mongo --host my_host --port my_port my_db create_indexes.js
```

Where `create_indexes.js` file will contain your commands:

```
db.getCollection("elements").ensureIndex({customerId:1});
db.getCollection("elements").ensureIndex({userId:1});
....
```

Comment: Yeah, also take a look here for some pointers: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell

Comment: Works good for me.. :) BTW.. Will it work fine in a Sharded enviornment? I mean if i run it on the mongos shell will it reflect on the shards I am running or i ll have to run the .js separately on my shards?

Comment: If you run it against `mongos`, it will execute on all shards.

Answer (score 8):

You can also run the script from the mongodb shell. I like adding things to a function to make it convenient to call them. Create the script like this:

```
var ensureIndexes = function() {
    db.getCollection("elements").ensureIndex({customerId:1});
    db.getCollection("elements").ensureIndex({userId:1}); ........
}
```

Save the above to a file named ensureIndexes.js, then from the mongo shell enter:

```
load('ensureIndexes.js')
```

Now you will be able to enter `ensureIndexes()` to call that function. I have a lot of scripts containing utility functions like that.

Comment: This is a nice trick to work with, that will ensure our custom functions other than the js functions provided by mongodb shell.. :) BTW... Will it work fine in a Sharded enviornment? I mean if i run it on the mongos shell will it reflect on the shards I am running or i ll have to run the .js separately on my shards?

Comment: @juhi Yes, you can do that. See this page: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution especially the section on storing scripts server-side. You can then run them anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using any unix like OS, it might help.

I did a redirect using unix shell.

So from UNIX command line you type:

```
mongo < your_script.js
```

Inside the your_script.js you can state your commands.